# Слайдер внутри слайдера

Tags: jquery, slider, html, css, javascript

Основной слайдер сделал с помощью flexsider. А вот с внутренним возникают проблемы, не могу подобрать никакой. Сложность еще в том, что он с превью изображений. Может, посоветуете что.
Вот примерный макет:

[image]

Comment: так вам нужно уже что то готовое слайдер в слайдере + сразу там и превью на слайде?
такое врядли сразу из коробки будет, но есть классный слайдер http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

Comment: Я понимаю, что такого не будет сразу в коробке, поэтому и собираю по частям. Основной слайдер сделал, и он меня полностью устраивает, а вот внутренний с превью слайдов не могу найти - либо не то, либо весь слайдер уезжает. Может, такое проще сделать на jquery ну или есть легенький слайдер.

Comment: реализовал на js